# Declaring instances in C#

Tags: c#, syntax

Do I have to "double declare" every new instance in c#?

```
Obj sb = new Obj();
```

VB is cheaper

```
Dim sb as new Obj()
```

and Python cheapest

```
sb=Obj()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, as of C# 3 you can use `var` for local variables:

```
var x = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Note that this is very different from the Python declaration: the variable `x` is still of type `Dictionary<string, string>`; it's just that the compiler has inferred the type from the right-hand side of the assignment. So you'll still get IntelliSense support and all the other benefits of static typing. (If you want dynamic typing, you can use `dynamic` as of C# 4, but that's a very different feature.)

This feature was partly added to support anonymous types, although it's very useful in other cases too; most notably when you *are* calling a constructor.

A few things to bear in mind:

- It *only* applies to local variables, not instance or static variables
- You can only use it when you're declaring and assigning in the same statement
- The compiler has to be able to infer a concrete type from the assignment; you can't write

  ```
  var x = null;
  ```

  for example.
- Bear readability in mind. If it's not obvious what kind of type is being assigned, consider using an explicit declaration
- If you later want to assign a less-specific expression, you may want to use explicit typing
- Implicit typing helps to emphasize *what* the code is doing rather than *how* it's doing it; for bits of code where the "how" is particularly important, consider still using an explicit declaration

Comment: Ah, great. *remember to check as solution, just have to wait 13 minutes for some reason.*

Comment: @joeriks: The "some reason" is that a better answer may come along in that time. Of course a better answer could *always* come along later on, but it gives everyone else a chance to get in there while the question is still relatively fresh.

Comment: @joeriks, dit you test the answer for proof in any way? I am not doubting about Jon's answer, but instantly accepting any (elaborated) answer that sounds good helps nobody ;) Especially when the answer is completely wrong.. so beware to be too quick (no offense)

Comment: In Python the x will be of type Dictionary aswell. (Tested in IronPython) this returns "System.Text.StringBuilder": x = System.Text.StringBuilder()
print x.GetType() (... and IntelliSense with the IronPython VS plugin ...)

Comment: @joeriks: yes, in python `x = System.Text.StringBuilder()`
it's a stringbuilder as well, but after you can do `x = 3.5` and x will become a double. That's dynamic typing...

Comment: @joeriks: No, there's a difference between the type of the *variable* and the type of the object it's currently referring to. Suppose you wrote `object x = new StringBuilder()` in C# - then the type of the *variable* is `object`, but the type of the *value* is a reference to a `StringBuilder`. Big difference.

Answer (score 3):

In C# 3.0 and later you can now declare them using var.

```
var obj = new Obj();
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I blame typing on a mobile device ;)

Answer (score 0):

The following examples show some type inferences that happen without double explicit type specification (sometimes without any) as following:

```
 int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8 };


    var q = from x in array
            let y = x.ToString()
            select y;

    foreach (var item in q)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(item.GetType());

    }
```

1) the right hand side of array decalration shows the array initializer alone with no type specification. Array type specification used to be required in the past.
2) var q .... where q is inferred from the right hand side.
3) from x .... the type of this range variable is inferred from the array's element type
4) let y ... the type of range variable y is again inferred from right hand side
5) foreach (var item in q) ... again the type of item inferred and not explicitly declared

There are innumerable other  instances of type inference in modern versions of C# detailed in specs (e.g lamba expressions). So no , you dont have to specify it twice any more. Infact currently its quite rare to see a requirement of such explicit and potentially redundant specification (e.g. intance variable declaration)